# Dart code compiled to JS seems to be faster than Dart (in Dartium)

Tags: dart, dartium

Impressed by the performance of Dart I put together a quite simple web-app to render the Mandelbrot set in Dart (using HTML5 canvas). This is by all means not meant as a realistic performance test. The page renders the Mandelbrot set in a 800x600 canvas with a max-depth of 10.000.
The app can be seen here: http://goo.gl/DLuQp

What puzzles me: running in Dartium the image renders in about 8.5 seconds (which is impressive). The same page in Firefox takes >15 seconds. No surprise there.

But running the same page in Chrome (version 27.0.1453.93), which does not run Dart but the JS version as well completes in 6.7 seconds, faster than Dart?

Why is that so?

UPDATE:
I added a "Run" button to re-render the canvas (to verify warm-up behaviour). Also I added a JS-only version (same code of course) to check JS in Dartium. In short: the figures and my question remains as is. Warm-up seems to have no effect. The JS-version is faster in Dartium than the Dart-version.

UPDATE after closed question: Just for the record: in this specific case moving the code into parallel workers/isolates not only resulted in a significant performance boost, also Dart now clearly leaves the JS-version behind in the dust by factor 10.

Comment: I am just guessing, so here's a comment instead of an answer. Chrome has heavily optimized JS engine. Dartium is a development tool - I wouldn't be surprised if Dart VM is configured for debugging and not speed in this case. Additionally, although benchmarks show DartVM being faster than V8, these are general benchmarks. some parts (graphics?) could still be better optimized in V8

Comment: Are you running Dartium with "checked mode" turned on?  This adds an overhead as it asserts all the types at runtime (check Run>Settings).

Comment: Have you tested the js version in Dartium too?

Comment: Independent of your question: if you want to measure time-spans, use probably want to use the Stopwatch class and not DateTime.

Comment: See my update: I switched off checked mode in Dartedit, but maybe that is not enough. The JS-version in Dartium has about the same performance as in Chrome. I switched to Stopwatch class, thanks for the tip! Same times, but the Stopwatch class allows me to easily exclude the drawing of the pixel. Without those the execution times are quite similar between Dart and JS. Still the JS-version is somewhat faster. :)

Thanks a lot for all your comments!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a known issue with the canvas bindings and APIs. See http://dartbug.com/10344

Comment: That is very interesting, thanks! The latest version of my program excludes the call to the bindings (the stopwatch is stopped before the pixel is drawn and started again afterwards). Now the difference is very little. But JS still being a (little) bit faster.

Answer (score 8):

There could be several reasons. Out of the top of my head:

- Dart VM misses out on some optimizations. V8 is much older than the Dart-VM and some optimizations just didn't make it into Dart yet.
- You are not running a warmup run. The Dart-VM currently does not do OSR (on-stack replacement). When a function is invoked it will finish in the same "mode" in which it was started. That is, if an important function is started in non-optimized mode, but contains a loop that is really important (and runs for a long time) then the Dart VM will not replace it with the optimized version. An easy workaround is to execute the function (possibly with a smaller value) first so that the function gets optimized. Eventually OSR will make it into the Dart VM.
- Make sure you don't run in checked mode. The Dart-VM can be much faster in unchecked mode.

Comment: Thanks, Florian! Warm-up optimization does not seem to be the issue. I will try to run in unchecked mode (it seems to me that the switch in Dartedit is not actually switching checked mode off..?), this is the most plausible explanation left.